# Where `apex_application_page` tables are located (in SQL Developer)?

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm working with Oracle APEX 4.2 and have a connection to it from SQL Developer 4.1.5.21

I've found that many application related information are available in tables like

- APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_DA_ACTS
- APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_ITEMS
- APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_BUTTONS
- APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_PROC
- APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_REGIONS

However I couldn't find documentation of complete list of those tables.

I've also tried looking in SQL developer, but neither there (looking in tables / views / application express ...) could find them. Where are all those tables available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The objects you listed are just synonyms for the apex exposed metadata views. You can easily query those (view name + column name) with:

```
select * from apex_dictionary
```

Or just quickly get all the view names:

```
select distinct(apex_view_name) from apex_dictionary
```

These views all query the apex metadata, which is stored in the apex version schema. For example, for apex 4.2 this schema is called `APEX_040200`, for apex 5 `APEX_050000`, and so on. Though you will most likely not have direct access to a lot of the objects in there: you're supposed to work with the public (documented) api's and the public views.